# Got VS compiler warning C4239 when trying to cast std::vector<std::pair<T, U>> to its lvalue ref

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I have a class `Foo` whose constructor is written like

```
Foo::Foo(std::vector<std::pair<int, char>> &Data)
    : //Initialization list
{
    //Some other initialization
}
```

And I tried to invoke it in my code with

```
Foo(std::vector<std::pair<int, char>>
    {
        {10, 'a'}
    });
```

The compiler then gives me a C4239 saying that

```
nonstandard extension used: 'argument': conversion from 
'std::vector<std::pair<int,char>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 
'std::vector<std::pair<int,char>,std::allocator<_Ty>> &'
```

I understand the message but why is the compiler not happy about such conversion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not `std::make_pair`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

Consider:

```
Foo::Foo(const std::vector<std::pair<int, char>> &Data)
```

According to Bjarne Stroustrup's [C++11 - the new ISO C++ standard](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#rvall) (emphasis mine):

> In C++, non-const references can bind to lvalues and const references can bind to lvalues or rvalues, but there is nothing that can bind to a non-const rvalue. **That's to protect people from changing the values of temporaries that are destroyed before their new value can be used.**

Comment: Thanks. Adding const does resolve the warning. But why can't a temporary value bind to a non-const reference here?

Comment: @user3291342 The standard does not allow it, I think the rationale is that potential modifying a temporary might be confusing.